# Unknown content in the html div

Tags: javascript, html, web

I know this question is not a good one but I have stumbled upon on website called Tradingview.com which has awesome charts. I was interested so got into the html code of the website and I discovered that div which should have contained desired chart was empty. I get that the chart is generated by JavaScript but I am interested how it is possible to draw something like that without any html elements and If it is possible could you tell me what "library" do they use?
Here is the link to Apple Stock Chart 
https://www.tradingview.com/chart/BRuYnW6t/

Comment: You can add elements to DOM dynamically.

Comment: plus JS can be able to draw things. like lines and rectangular and circle shape.

Answer (score 1):

Basically Javascript literally Draw chart inside that div on local end.

like JS will make rectangular shapes. circles, lines and everything.

for details please visit this site.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_canvas.asp

drawing div will be empty but shapes and everything in it will be there because of JS.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like tradingview has an API for their library [available upon request](https://www.tradingview.com/HTML5-stock-forex-bitcoin-charting-library/). I would also encourage you check out [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/), a popular solution for implementing charts in javascript.

Comment: even chart.js draw basic shapes like rectangular and circle at lower level.

Answer (score 0):

Normally drawing in HTML is done with [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/kab/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) ([WebGL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API) for 3D drawings) or [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG). Additionally, you may use plugins like [Flash ActionScript](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning.html) and [Java Applets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_applet_basics.htm). For charts, a superb library would be [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery).

If you inspect carefully enough (F12), you will realize TradingView actually uses canvas for the drawing.

Comment: and JS use basic methods like fill or draw at the end ??

Comment: Yes, you draw on <canvas> with JavaScript.